# laravel eloquent 'has' method behaves in an unexpected way

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I want to get the collection of a Section model if it has at least one `User`. from the docs the `has()` method does this, great. The collection retrieved does not have the the `users` relationship in it. Yet when I loop through the collection , I can get the properties of the `users`. Why?

```
class Section extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User');
    }
}
```

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function section()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Section');
    }
}
```

what I did is this:

```
$section = Section::where('id' , 1)->has('users')->get();
```

the collection is this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3025
     all: [
       App\Section {#3015
         id: 1,
         class_id: 1,
         section_name: "A",
         created_at: "2019-12-14 18:26:01",
         updated_at: "2019-12-14 18:26:01",
       },
     ],
   }
```

Now the weird part is that when I do the following, it gives the properties of users even though in the collection the `users` relationship is not present.

**Why?**

```
 @foreach ($section as $section)
   @foreach ($section->users as $student)
     <p>{{$student->name}}</p>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

```
solomon
uche
kene
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just how Laravel works.

Accessing `$model->{relationship}`, in your case `$section->users`, is a magic function that checks if you have explicitly loaded the relationship via something like `Section::with('users')`, and if you haven't, loads it then.

The reason you're not seeing `users` when you run `dd($section)` is that you didn't explicitly load the relationship, but this does not mean that it is unavailable. If you included `with('users')` in your initial query, you'd see the following:

```
$section = Section::where('id' , 1)->has('users')->with('users')->get();

App\Section {#3015
   id: 1,
   class_id: 1,
   section_name: "A",
   created_at: "2019-12-14 18:26:01",
   updated_at: "2019-12-14 18:26:01",
   users: [
     0 => App\User {#3016}
       id: ...
       name: ...
   ]
 },

// Or similar
```

Basically, you weren't loading the relationship, so you aren't able to see it when using `dd($section)`, but it is still available in PHP, due to Laravel's magic methods.

I should note as well, use the correct variable naming and closure (`->get()`, `->first()`, etc) for your query.

`$section` is a poor name when using `->get()`, as you're getting multiple records back from the database. Either use `$sections`, or change the closure to `->first()`, and don't use a `foreach()` if you use `->first()`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I understand your question.

1. First

The `has` method does not mean that it's going to include `User`. It means that will return all the `sections` that have at least one user. I think there is/are users for `Section` id ===1. So, in your code with `has` or without it, it does not make any difference.

if you want to load a relationship explicit you should use `with`

`Section::where('id' , 1)->with('users')->get();`. Then you should have users collection under per section.

2. Second

   The reason why you can still access the user properties in your `blade` file, is because of `lazy loading`. even it's not included in the original DB query and result but when you are trying to access it laravel still tries to fetch those for you. And this may cause N+1 problem.

Comment: if you look at the collection, you will notice that there is no 'users' relationship, all I'm saying is that the loop should not have given the properties of the 'users' as the 'user' relationship is not present in the collection. but it does, that's why I'm confused and I want to know why this is happening like this.

Comment: This is mostly correct, however you can (and generally should) still use `has()` in conjunction with `with()`; `has()` will handle the count-based filtering of `Section`, `with()` with eager load the relationship to avoid the `N+1` issue as you mentioned. In the above code, you can still get `Section` models that don't have any `User`s, which seems to go against the original question's intention.

Comment: @TimLewis I think he is confused with `has` method, he thinks `has` means include the relationship, which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your first echo:

```
$section = Section::where('id' , 1)->has('users')->get();
```

Just prints the section where it has a user, but you're not specifically saying give me the users as well.

In the next loop you are looping over each section in the view, and specifically saying loop the relationship. this is visible by this line: `@foreach ($section->users as $student)`

Im reading the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

In your first echo when printing the section you can get the users like so: `echo $section-> users()`

Comment: most of this is pseudo code as I dont have a laravel environment available to me at this time on my new computer.

Comment: you are right, just went through the docs now, an it clearer to me now..